# Why are some Bestiary entries yellow?

Tags: vampire-survivors

See this screenshot of the Bestiary:

[image]

Why are Skeleton, Lionhead, Milk Elemental and Dragon Shrimp written in yellow font? There are more entries like, but I think they are less than 10% of all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yellow entry enemies are the ones you need to kill to unlock new characters or achievements.

Also confirmed in this Steam [thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1794680/discussions/0/3418811628267351344/) by one of the developers who confirmed a similar answer.

Comment: Oh, I see, looks like they are also stay yellow even when you completed related achievements